# AWS S3 CLI not working after Ubuntu "do-release-upgrade"

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

The happy little nag about the "do-release-upgrade" finally got me the other day. Updating the system went as expected and I worked a couple of hours fixing the obvious errors that popped up. The only thing I have no idea and can't find any documentation on is the S3 command that I set up to copy backup files from my EC2 instance over to the S3 bucket. This is the command that I have in the cron.daily script:

```
mysqldump -u admin -p'myPasswordHere' myDbNameHere > "$_file"
aws s3 cp "$_file" s3://my-backup-bucket/mysql/
```

This worked before the upgrade (from LTS 14.04 to LTS 16.04). Now I have the error:

```
upload failed: tmp/MyDbNameHere_03_16_2017.sql.gz to 
s3://my-backup-bucket/mysql/MyDbNameHere_03_16_2017.sql.gz 
An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation:
Missing required header for this request: x-amz-content-sha256
```

I don't know how I am "missing required header" - but that seems to be the problem.

The same but different error occurs from the command line:

```
root@sys:~# aws s3 cp "dead.letter" s3://my-backup-bucket/
upload failed: ./dead.letter to s3://my-backup-bucket/dead.letter 
An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the PutObject operation:
Missing required header for this request: x-amz-content-sha256
```

*edit - I did upgrade `awscli` to the newest version as suggested. Did not fix issue.

Comment: When is the last time you updated the `aws` command?  Not sure if it's related but it gets updated very frequently.

Comment: Never have - unless it is part of the apt-get upgrade routine??

Comment: Updated `awscli` via `pip` to newest version 1.11.63

Comment: Ok, you're doing it differently than I am.  I just have the Ubuntu package "awscli" installed from the Ubuntu packages.  I'm running `aws-cli/1.11.13 Python/3.5.2 Linux/4.4.0-57-generic botocore/1.4.70` (aws --version) - interesting that the included version is so much older than what you've got.

Comment: Aptitude has an ancient version of aws-cli @stdunbar.  Using `pip` is the recommended practice.

Comment: Still haven't found an answer. I posted essentially the same question to the AWS forum and haven't yet received any response. My solution was to mount the S3 bucket and just `cp` the files instead of using the AWS CLI method.